# Compilation error after linking lottie-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, lottie

I tried to link lottie-ios but I have a compilation error. 
Lottie works fine with the android emulator.

Here is what I did:
1. npm i --save lottie-react-native@2.3.2
2. react-native link lottie-ios
3. react-native link lottie-react-native
4. After this, open the Xcode project configuration and add the Lottie.framework as Embedded Binaries

I have multiple compilation errors starting by this one:

```
/Users/user/Code/CSULB/CECS_543/anacodiam_ios/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/../../../react-native/ReactCommon/fabric/graphics/platform/ios/float.h:8:10: fatal error: "limits" file not found
    #include <limits>
    While building module "UIKit" imported from /Users/user/Code/CSULB/CECS_543/anacodiam_ios/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTViewManager.h:8:
    While building module "Foundation" imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: fatal error: could not build module "CoreFoundation"
    #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

My React-native version:

```
react-native -V
0.57.4
```

**Screenshots**
Here is my project settings (File > Project Settings):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h649V.jpg

My general settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWBUJ.jpg

My Header Search paths: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svHCV.jpg

I added `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/` as recommanded in this issue [Github](https://github.com/react-community/lottie-react-native/issues/373)

And my build phases:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6z99.jpg

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use react-native link. It doesn't work in most of case. Using manual linking https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anhtu said, automatic linking might be broken for lottie.
Also, I had the same compilation problem : you should update `lottie-react-native` to latest version (2.5.9 at this date), they fixed their iOS project `header search path` setting.

In version 2.5.8, their project referenced `React` folder with recursive option, which caused the CodeFoundation build error. (this used to be recommended by ReactNative, but it has changed since : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)
They've removed this `header search path` since 2.5.9, and now this CoreFoundation error has gone !

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the version of lottie-react-native and it fixed every compilation errors I had. (They could have updated their doc...)